# Mailchimp Webhooks API v3

Tags: mailchimp, webhooks

I am new to mailchimp API and i need to work on v3, everything is going good as expected. I need to create a webhook for a list similar to  [webhook-add in v2](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/webhook-add.php) But i could not find the [resource](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources) for webhooks in API v3. I have tried multiple collections like `lists/<list_id>/webhooks-add` and `lists/<list_id>/webhooks` etc and i am getting `The resource could not be found.`

Is mailchimp webhooks APIs deprecated in v3 ? OR they have been renamed in v3 ? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just want to update this thread, may be this could help some one out there.

At the time of this post there were no webhooks in Mailchimp API V3 but they have added now. [Here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/webhooks/) is the link for webhooks in Mailchimp API V3.

Comment: You can change which answer you accepted for this question — choosing your own answer.  There is nothing wrong with this, as it is the best thing for the SO community.

Answer (score 6):

Webhooks are not yet implemented in API v3.

Comment: This seemed exactly so to me as well, so i have used v2 api to add webhooks to lists, as that was a one time use for me so it don't bother to use v2 api once. :)

Answer (score 0):

webhooks has not been implemented yet in v3. i have used v2 for implementing webhooks